# Why my local PostgreSQL database push to my Heroku Postgres doesn't work?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, plpgsql, heroku-postgres

I created a private AWS S3 bucket and put inside my database.dump file, that I created with this commande:

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydatabase > mydatabase.dump
```

Then, I created a pressigned url :

```
aws s3 presign s3://fivbackup/strapifivfr.pgsql --expires-in 604800 --region eu-west-3
```

I was able to download the file by following the signed URL.

When I try this commande I get an error:

```
    heroku pg:backups:restore 'RAW_SIGNED_URL' -a fivteam2 DATABASE_URL
    
    //
    Restoring... !
! An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
!
! pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file
! pg_restore finished with errors
! waiting for download to complete
! download finished with errors
! please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible

heroku pg:backups:info r013:
=== Backup r013
Database: BACKUP
Started at: 2021-08-27 15:17:09 +0000
Finished at: 2021-08-27 15:17:10 +0000
Status: Failed
Type: Manual
Backup Size: 0.00B (0% compression)

=== Backup Logs
2021-08-27 15:17:10 +0000 2021/08/27 15:17:10 aborting: could not write to output stream: Expected HTTP Status 200, received: "400 Bad Request"
2021-08-27 15:17:10 +0000 waiting for restore to complete
2021-08-27 15:17:10 +0000 pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file
2021-08-27 15:17:10 +0000 pg_restore finished with errors
2021-08-27 15:17:10 +0000 waiting for download to complete
2021-08-27 15:17:10 +0000 download finished with errors
2021-08-27 15:17:10 +0000 please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible
```

I alsoI also tried the commande `heroku pug:push mydatabase DATABASE_URL -a myapp` but couldn't set up the PGUSER variable (not recognized term).
Ps: I'm on windows

Answer (score 0):

Update : I pushed my database in public mode instead of using a presign url (not the best option but I will keep digging), but this below might help a few newbies like me:

**1:** One of the problem I had was also having an invalid dump file format. I tried to restore my dump file in TablePlus to test the format, it didn't work.
So, instead of using the CLI to generate a dump, I used TablePlus and selected the custom format option. I then tested if the file format would be accepted this time by restoring it in TablePlus: it worked !

**2:** I think I misunderstood up my autorisation settings in AWS S3, I'm still very confused with the *public vs private Buckets* and *public vs private files*

**3:** I realised my VSCode console changed the url I pasted into string, somehow so I used the Desktop CLI instead.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.